# Calling a function when emacs process is killed (MS Windows)

Tags: hooks, microsoft-windows, exit

I would like to call a function just before emacs exits. Normally the following can do job:

```
(add-hook 'kill-emacs-hook 'my-function)
```

Unfortunately when I shutdown the system (MS Windows) or terminating the emacs process by some external tools, this does not work.

Is it impossible to achieve this goal in such situations?

Answer (score 2):

The manual explicitly states that `kill-emacs` is called, running the `kill-emacs-hook`, when `SIGTERM` or `SIGKILL` is recieved. So I would call this a bug.

https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Killing-Emacs.html

(I guess this has to do with how windows kills differently than POSIX, but it should be possible to implement the analog/correct behaviour.)